# How to suppress record sets returned by SELECT statements in a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm writing a stored procedure which checks for the existence of various tables in various databases, as well as the permissions that the user executing the stored procedure has on those tables. The stored procedure itself resides within a user database (i.e. it's not in the Master db).

To perform my checks, my stored procedure contains lots of `SELECT` statements. Each of those obviously returns a record set. What I would like is to somehow suppress these record sets so that they are not returned by the stored procedure, and instead return my own, single record set which is just a collection of messages relating to each check the stored procedure performs.

I think the obvious answer is to use a table-valued function instead, but I've not been able to recreate my tests successfully in a Function as they appear in the stored procedure. For starters, I'm having to use temporary tables (not possible in a function) and dynamic SQL (not very compatible with table parameters).

I think I've basically got two choices:

- Rewrite my stored procedure as a function and figure out how to do the checks a different way.
- Continue using my stored procedure and use an `OUTPUT` parameter to return my result messages, probably as a delimited string, and in the associated ASP.NET application just ignore all the record sets the stored procedure returns .

Neither of these solutions is very satisfactory. Before I spend any more time pursuing either one, is there a way to discard the record sets produced by the `SELECT` statements in a stored procedure and explicitly define what record I want it to return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, I only can speculate here...

Are you using something like

```
SELECT ...;
IF @@rowcount > 0
BEGIN
  ...
END;
```

?

Then you can rewrite it using something like

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT ...)
BEGIN
  ...
END;
```

or

```
DECLARE @variable integer;
SELECT @variable = count(*) ...;
IF @variable > 0
BEGIN
  ...
END;
```

In general point the results of your queries to a target (variable, table, expression, ...), then they don't get outputted.

And then just execute the query for your desired result in the end.

Comment: Selecting the results into variables was just what I needed, I don't know why I didn't think of it myself, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, here is almost no reason to have stored procedures produce record sets.  That is what stored functions are for.  On occasion, it is needed, because of the use of dynamic SQL or other stored procedures, but not as a general practice.  Much, much too often, I see stored procedures being used where stored functions or views are more appropriate.

What should you do?  Even `SELECT` statement in the stored procedure should be one of the following:

- Setting (local) variables.
- Saving the results in a temporary table or table variable.

The logic for the stored procedure should be working on the local variables.  The results should be returned using `OUTPUT` parameters.

If you need to return rows in a tabular format, you can do that using tables explicitly (such as a global temporary table or real table).  Or, you can have one `SELECT` at the end that does return a single result set.  However, if you need this and can phrase the stored procedure as a function, that is better in my opinion.

Comment: You're right that a function is what's required here really, and I agree with you that SPs are used where functions would be the more appropriate choice far too often. However, with me needing to use temporary tables and dynamic SQL which precludeds table variables I think I'm stuck with an SP on this occasion.